# How to Build a Facebook-like Platform on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, soa, restful-authentication, architecture

I am interested to build a platform on Google App Engine where one Master App provides common functionality to several child Apps (Web portals).

*Master App*:

- Offers Common Social Networking features
- Common user database
- Interacts using Web services API

*Child Apps (Web Portals)*:

- Connects to Master App for user database and social networking features
- Uses Local business logic for local features

My Design plan is:

1. Master and Child Apps will be
   individual Apps on GAE Appspot (for
   easy management)
2. All will communicate via REST/JSON?
3. I will enable billing for all Apps so
   nothing is against Google's usage
   policy.
4. Will use SSL for login into Master App, later use a token
   (cookie) for further interactions

Could anyone kindly spot risks and suggest any improvements?

Comment: Don't do that with SSL, it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that "Master and Child" relations will make for easier management.  Could you explain?  If you give that up, then 1., 2., and 3. become irrelevant.  And 4. is neither here nor there.

Comment: @Fibericon: As all my Apps are private and I need to safeguard their data, I am thinking of SSL. Will this be slower? Do you think there is a better way? Please suggest.

Comment: @Glenn: You are right, they are all just Apps depending on certain other Web Services to offer their functionality.

Comment: @Glenn: Making this entire platform as a Single App would be really complex and not manageable. Thats why I am thinking of breaking them up into individual Apps so that they can be easily upgraded and managed.

Comment: Are these 'child apps' independent, like facebook apps? Can anyone develop one? If not, you should make them part of the main app - if you think that's unmanageable, you simply need to learn to manage a large codebase better.

Comment: @Nick: I partly agree with you, but if you have something like Yahoo Movies, Yahoo Finance, Yahoo Mail all as child Apps which use the core services of Yahoo such as Membership, then what is the best way to build such as solution on GAE, keeping their TOS in mind?

Comment: @Nick: OK, if the child apps are meant for third party developers, in that case, would this Architecture be suitable?

Comment: @charming30 In the "Yahoo *" case, they're separate sites, which just happen to share branding and authentication, so separate apps are perfectly sensible. Likewise, in the case of apps written by third party developers, you have to provide some external protocol - but it should work for any webapp, not just App Engine apps.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Master/Child" concept will be hard to maintain, introduce issues with cross-site-scripting and most importantly be completely against Google App Engine's [terms of service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html) for combining multiple apps into one.

> 4.4. You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a single Application or otherwise access the Service in a manner intended to avoid incurring fees.

Comment: ...as pointed out when the OP specifically asked this question about the TOS in his previous SO question.

Comment: Will this rule apply even if enable Billing on all Apps? I dont intend to avoid fees, I just need a distributed system which I can maintain and upgrade independently.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. Even if unintentionally, you *will* be avoiding fees as each app comes with it's own free-quota billing enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple app versions (defined on app.yaml) to deploy different codebases to the same appspot.com subdomain, and access them like http://app1.myapp.appspot.com, http://app2.myapp.appspot.com for "versions" app1 and app2. You could even have one version running on Java and another one on Python.
They'll all share the same datastore, although you'd be able to use namespaces to separate them if necessary.

For the distributed nature of the architecture you proposed, I'd suggest having a deep look at Facebook's graph API and Twitter's API. They both use oAuth for authentication/authorization and already have a proven implementation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sounds very good, I think this may also be in line with Google TOS, as all Apps will dependent on one Quota. I could use name spaces to separate data for various Apps.. Thanks a lot for this..

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the Facebook and Twitter API as suggested.